# What is the lifetime of a temporary object bound to a reference in a new-initializer?

Tags: c++, reference, new-operator, object-lifetime, temporary-objects

From [[class.temporary]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj#class.temporary-6.12) of the *Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++*:

> (6.12) — A temporary bound to a reference in a *new-initializer* ([expr.new]) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the *new-initializer*.
>
> [*Note 7*: This might introduce a dangling reference. — *end note*]
>
> [*Example 5:*
>
> ```cpp
> struct S { int mi; const std::pair<int,int>& mp; };
> S a { 1, {2,3} };
> S* p = new S{ 1, {2,3} };       // creates dangling reference
> ```
>
> — *end example*]

Does it mean that the temporary object `{2,3}` bound to the reference member `mp` of `S` persists until the evaluation of the expression `new S { 1, {2,3} }`, or until the evaluation of the expression `S* p = new S{ 1, {2,3} }`?

Comment: Full-expression is `S* p = new S{ 1, {2,3} }`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full-expression is `S* p = new S{ 1, {2,3} }`.

Comment: To be a little more technical, that's not an expression, but the full-expression here does include the initialization of `p` ([intro.execution]/5). Not that the initialization part matters for object lifetime.